# How do I add an onclick event handler to an anchor tag using JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to add an `onclick` event to a anchor tag:

```
    $recipe += '<a class="add-bookmark" href="#">Add bookmark</a>'; //Add event to this


function addEventListeners() {
        $(document).on("click", ".add-bookmark", function() {
            alert("done");
        });
    }

addEventListeners();
```

How do I add an event handler dynamically in JQuery?

Update: The issue has been solved when I put event handler code to above function contains  tags

Comment: Do you really want it to add a book mark on document? Or do you want to add that event handler to a clickable item, like a button or a link?

Comment: I want to add that event handler to a clickable item, :)

Comment: First, you had a lot of code that wasn't needed to show us your particular problem. Secondly, do you want to add that event handler to *all* clickable items? Or specific `<a>` tags or `<div>`s?

Comment: I dont see anything wrong with your JS code

Comment: And I put class for the purpose is add event handler to all clickable items, those's <a> tags.

Comment: shaunakde, Yep, me too. But I still can't run it with event.

Comment: Add `preventDefault()`

Answer (score 2):

Use this in case of `<a>`

```
 $(document).on("click", ".add-bookmark", function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();    //prevent default action of <a>
        alert("done");
 });
```

Comment: thank! But it don't work for me.

Comment: Have you included jQuery reference?

Comment: of course. I think issue in this element but i don't what is it.

Answer (score 0):

try to use the following piece of code.

```
$('a.add-bookmark').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault(); //if you want to prevent the default action for anchor elements.
    //write your statements.
    alert('done');
});
```